# How to retrieve and set the title of a page from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to set the title of my main (parent) page dynamically from the title of the page in the iframe.

For example I have two pages, Index.html and frame.html.

Now Index.html is having an iframe which is connected to frame.html something like this:

```
<iframe allowtransparency=true scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="frame.html"></iframe>
```

frame.html is having code:

```
<head>
<title> Main Title </title>
</head>
<body>
body text
</body>
```

Now I want the title of Index.html, be retrieved from frame.html's `<title>` tag, i.e., " Main Title".

Can someone show me how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Do the parent `window` and `iframe` `window` have the same origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<iframe allowtransparency=true scrolling="auto" id="my-iframe" frameborder="0" src="frame.html"></iframe>
<script>
    $("#my-iframe").on('load',function() {
        document.title = document.getElementById("my-iframe").contentDocument.title;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry its not working. The title of the index.html is still not coming. I just copied the same code you posted in the index.html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery library in your index.html file?  If so, it needs to be loaded above the code I posted.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Just one last question, if I wanted to use web page on another domain instead of frame.html, would there be any way to make it work?

Comment: No I'm afraid that the XSS security restrictions in all major browsers prevent that.  It basically means that you cannot use javascript to read/manipulate pages accross different domains.

Comment: Thank you, this works well on load, but I need to be able to detect when the title within the iFrame changes so that I can update the title of the browser tab.

Comment: @MattWeiler The naive method (and probably the easiest) to do that is to just run a method on an interval (using setInterval()), which checks the title of the iframe and if it has changed since the last check, then update the title of the parent.